# Undo a file association

Tags: windows-7, zip

This is probably one of the stupidest things I've ever done and won't be doing again.

Basically, I figured since .jar files are effectively .zip files and normally you can use explorer.exe to open .zip files, opening .jar files with .zip files would work, then I wouldn't have to keep using 7zip all the time.

I was wrong, turns out it just causes explorer to clog up.

That would be fine had I not forgotten about windows' little 'Always use this program to open the selected kind of file' checkbox. Which is checked by default and I forgot to un-check.

So my question is "Is there anyway to undo this mistake?"

Before people start telling me registry keys, assoc and ftype, I have checked ftype and assoc, they claim jarfiles still open with javaw.exe like they should. I have also looked with regedit at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.jarfile, it says the same. HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Classes doesn't contain keys for .jar or jarfile, no matter where I look I can't see any registry-related issue.

I'm thinking only a system restore will sort this. Luckily my last restore point is 3 days ago, I've checked and it says no programs will be affected (so I'm assuming all those masses of file move operations I've been doing will be safe). 
Before I do resort to that however, I want to check that there is no easier option.
Any useful input is appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to this question:

http://superuser.com/questions/355333/why-are-certain-default-application-associations-locked?rq=1

Went to 

*HKEY_CURRENT_USER* -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> CurrentVersion -> Explorer -> FileExts > .jar

and deleted the progID relation so it defaults to the normal stuff.
Why Microsoft ever devised such a convoluted way of setting user file associations I will never know.