# Can't un-associate .css extension from Visual Stdio 2013

Tags: windows-7, file-association, visual-studio, css, file-extension

In  - `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations`

under `.css` file , it has `Microsoft Visual Stdio 2013` as `Currect Defualt`  -

[image]

I try to change its current default under the `Change program...` button to `Notepad++` -

**Update:**

(Note that the checkbox `Always use the selected program to open this kine of file` is on disable)

[image]

but after I do it nothing change about `.css` extension and it continue to be associated to `Microsoft Visual Stdio 2013` .

How to make it `Notepad++` associated constantly  ?

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox "Always use the selected program to open this kine of file"?

Comment: It on disable..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/355333/why-are-certain-default-application-associations-locked . The OP explains how you could solve this, but it remains open why those associations are locked.