# How to remove extension association using regedit.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, notepad++, file-association

Following my post here  - [Can't un-associate .css extension from Visual Stdio 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/752264/cant-un-associate-css-extension-from-visual-stdio-2013)

and the suggested solution  - [Why are certain default application associations "locked"?](https://superuser.com/questions/355333/why-are-certain-default-application-associations-locked)

What do I have to do in the `regedit.exe` in order to remove the `.css` association to Visual Studio and make it associate to `Notepad++` instead  ?

That what I have under -

```
regedit.exe -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> CurrentVersion -> Explorer -> FileExts > .css
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer seems to be highly Google-able. http://jesin.tk/delete-file-association-windows-7/

Comment: Please add your solution as answer. This will help others having the same issue to find the solution quickly. Also, make it verbose enough to be helpful. Or, you can simply delete your question.

Comment: @Danatela : Done , my dear .

Answer (score 1):

As describe in the attached link of @Farag - just do -

Go to -

`regedit.exe -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> CurrentVersion -> Explorer -> FileExts > .css`

Delete the `.css` folder,   like this -

[image]

and then that's extension would be not associate for any program .

Now you can set its new default program by -

[image]